ERROR AL INSTALAR primeng ANGULAR
Hola buenas estoy intentando instalar npm i primeng  me sale este error al momento de instalar
 Tengo angular la versión Angular CLI: 14.2.12
Node: 20.11.1 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 10.2.4 
OS: win32 x64 



PS D:\MIS\Front> npm i primeng        
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: stg-app-mis-r22@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^14.2.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from primeng@17.18.12
npm ERR! node_modules/primeng
npm ERR!   primeng@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\TPFLE002\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-02T21_33_49_297Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\TPFLE002\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-02T21_33_49_297Z-debug-0.log
PS D:\MIS\Front>


¿Has instalado Angular primero?

@fredyfx si claro hermanito tengo esta versión: angular la versión Angular CLI: 14.2.12
Node: 20.11.1 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 10.2.4
OS: win32 x64

ahí el error dice que la librería primeng pide angular 17 o angula 18, tienes que actualizar angular o instalar una vesión antigua de primeng como npm i primeng@14

@LPZadkiel me sale este added 1 package, changed 2 packages, and audited 1120 packages in 17s
129 packages are looking for funding
run npm fund for details
33 vulnerabilities (4 low, 13 moderate, 12 high, 4 critical)
To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix
To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force
Run npm audit for details.

looks gud! dale run a ver que pasa :E

@LPZadkiel ng serve -o ? Soy nuevo disculpa

claro ng serve y ver si arroja algun error

@LPZadkiel no me da errores pero al querer colocar CalendarModule no lo reconoce

@PieroDev, con este último comentario, el problema original de tu pregunta, lo estás derivando. ¿pudiste instalar el Angular junto con el PrimeNG?

Usualmente este error se debe a problemas con la versión que quieres instalar o por un desajuste de versiones entre Angular y PrimeNG
Estás usando la versión 20.11.1 de Node.js y ya no es compatible con la versión 14.2.12 de Angular y esto se debe a que Angular 14 es solo compatible con las versiones 14.x y 16.x de Node.js. Puedes arreglar este problema usando una versión anterior de Node.js
Otro error es que en tu proyecto utiliza @angular/common@14.3.0, pero la versión de PrimeNG que estás intentando instalar (primeng@17.18.12) requiere la versión @angular/common ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0. Esto significa que la versión 17 de PrimeNG no es compatible con Angular 14. Como dije anteriormente, esto es por la versión de Angular 14 pero puedes resolverlo también con esto:

Intenta instalar la primera versión de PrimeNG y verifica que sea compatible con Angular 14 (consulta la documentación)
Actualiza Angular (en caso de que quieras usar la última versión de PrimeNG) a una versión compatible como Angular 17 o 18

Si aún quieres usar Angular 14 puedes ejecutar:
npm install primeng@14.x

Si decides actualizar Angular puedes ejecutar:
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli

Después de actualizar Angular puedes instalar la última versión de PrimeNG y ya podrías trabajar bien

a mi me paso lo mismo con reactjs hace poquito y se supone que npx ya esta deprecated y ahora debo usar vite no se si funcione igual con angular pero con react si jalo
antes:
npx create-react-app my-app

Ahora:
vite create-react-app my-app


Esto no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta :(
